# How do i access the currentIndex from gridview in qml and update it on changed [In QML]

Tags: qml

How can I get the currentIndex from the gridView and highlight it and update back the currentIndex once it's changed to another item? [IN QML]. Please let me know what is the solution.

Thank you in advance!

```
GridView{
        id: colorGrid
        model: colorModelData

        delegate: ItemDelegate{
            id: colorcomboDelegate
            background: Rectangle {
                id: colorRect
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                width: colorGrid.cellWidth * 0.6
                height: colorGrid.cellWidth * 0.6
                radius: width/2
                color: colorModelData[index]  
            }
            Rectangle {
                id:colorSelectedRing
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                width: colorRect.width * 1.30
                height: width
                radius: width/2
                z:-1
                visible: index=== colorGrid.currentIndex? true:false [...ERROR]
                Rectangle {
                    id:colorSelectedBlackRing
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    width: colorRect.width * 1.13
                    height: width
                    radius: width/2
                }
            }
        }

        currentIndex: [Need to update the current index]
  }
```

Comment: What is 'control.highlightedIndex` ? What is the error message?

Comment: Sorry, my bad I was trying something there with control.highlightedIndex. I have edited it now @Amfasis

Comment: ok, that should work (no need to put the `? true : false` btw). So, what is the error message? What do you import?

Comment: Its working fine for currentIndex, but i want to update the currentIndex whenever the click is made on other cell

Comment: You probably want to add a `MouseArea` to `ItemDelegate`. Can you also post how `ItemDelegate` looks like? Then i can write an answer

Comment: I have added mouseArea and checked it,

Comment: I haved added this code below  background: Rectangle  element
                MouseArea{
                    anchors.fill: colorRect
                    onClicked: {colorGrid.currentIndex = colorGrid.currentIndex
                    console.log(colorGrid.currentIndex, colorGrid.currentItem)
                    }
                }
console log gets printed only for the last row of gridview

Comment: you should do `onClicked: { colorGrid.currentIndex = index; }`

Comment: okay, for which element i should anchors.fill  in mouseArea? to perform onClicked?

Comment: Where you want the click to be handled. If you want the whole ItemDelegate, you should do `anchors.fill: colorRect`. Another option would be `colorcomboDelegate`, which is possibly bigger. (to me, `colorSelectRing` does not make sense since that is hidden sometimes)